# optimization for large byte[]

Tags: c#, .net

I have 5MB byte[] which i write in chunks of 2k to the disk.
to get the chuck of 2k (c_writeSizeInBytes) i do :

```
int numberOfIterations = bytes.Length / c_writeSizeInBytes;
                    for (int i = 0; i < numberOfIterations; i++)
                    {
                        bool nearEnd = bytes.Length - i == c_writeSizeInBytes;
                        byte[] buffer = nearEnd ? bytes.Skip(i * c_writeSizeInBytes).ToArray() : bytes.Skip(i * c_writeSizeInBytes).Take(c_writeSizeInBytes).ToArray();
                        binaryWriter.Write(buffer, 0, c_writeSizeInBytes);

                    }
```

The performance is very slow for 5MB files after 2MBs. Is there any way to optimize it ?

thanks

Comment: Would [`File.WriteAllBytes`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/system.io.file.writeallbytes.aspx) work for you?

Comment: what type is `bytes`? A `byte[]`?

Comment: @AdamHouldsworth, i must write 2k chunks

Comment: @eugeneK I don't see why you need to personally.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Your use of `Skip` / `Take` / `ToArray` is very inefficient here. If you ***had*** to write in chunks, then you should just pass the offset into `Write`, i.e.

```
binaryWriter.Write(buffer, i * CHUNK_SIZE, CHUNK_SIZE);
```

(perhaps using some `Math.Min` in the final chunk to get hold of the remaining count, in case it isn't a full number of chunks)

However, there is no need to do this if you already have the data as a `byte[]` - just make one call to `Write`.

```
binaryWriter.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
```

If you are writing the entire file (i.e. this data *replaces* the old data, if any), then just use `File.WriteAllBytes`.

Answer (score 3):

I would write it like this:

```
byte[] input;

using(var inStream = new MemoryStream(input))
using(var outStream = File.OpenWrite("c:\\file.dat"))
{
    inStream.CopyTo(outStream, 2048);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Ah, you've got a [Schlemiel the Painter](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/fog0000000319.html) situation in there. Your for-loop involves seeking through the byte array (via .Skip()) one element at a time, and each iteration goes a bit further through the array, thus it takes longer and longer to complete each for-loop iteration the more iterations you've done.

Since you already have a byte array, why do you need a buffer at all? You can write to your binary stream directly from your existing array:

```
int offset = 0, lastFullWriteIndex = bytes.Length - c_writeSizeInBytes;
while (offset < lastFullWriteIndex)
{
    binaryWriter.Write(bytes, offset, c_writeSizeInBytes);
    offset += c_writeSizeInBytes;
}
binaryWriter.Write(bytes, offset, bytes.Length - offset);
```

Not only does this eliminate the slowing effect of successively walking more and more of the array, but it eliminates the extra work copying your bytes to a buffer.

Comment: Updated to move the extra conditional check out of the loop body, should be even faster now.

Answer (score 0):

Don't know what kind of constraints you have which force you to write only 2k chunk size But if you are bound to do this then try this method

```
  public void Write(Byte[] bytes,System.IO.Stream stream)
    {
        int chunkSize = 2 * 1024; //2k
        int offset = 0;
        do
        {
            var count = offset + chunkSize > bytes.Length ? bytes.Length - offset : chunkSize;
            stream.Write(bytes, offset, count);
            offset += count;

        } while (offset < bytes.Length);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

ok, if you want to roll your own (there is no need) this is a way to do it.

```
const int BufferSize = 2000
for (int left = bytes.Length; left > 0; left -= BufferSize)
{
    if (left < BufferSize)
    {
        binaryWriter.Write(byte, bytes.length - left, left);
        break;
    }

    binaryWriter.Write(byte, bytes.length - left, BufferSize);
}
```